# Can't Generate Signed APK after renaming Package

Tags: android, package, rename, release

I renamed my package this way:

> Another good method is: First create a new package with the desired name by right clicking on the java folder -> new -> package.
>
> Then, select and drag all your classes to the new package. AndroidStudio will refactor the package name everywhere.
>
> Finally, delete the old package.
>
> Done.

When I debug app or run app on my device everything's working fine. But when I try Generate Signed APK there's error:
[image: Picture]

I believe it has something to do with this:

> good method but had to do 2 more things(other than updating manifest file) to make it completely work, firstly had to change/rename the R file imports in whole project and secondly appdebug was using old package name( visible in run window of studio) added applicationId "com.packagename" in app build.gradle defaultconfig

**But I don't know what means "change/rename the R file imports".**

Everything's fine but "cannot find symbol variable". That's strange becouse when I see code everything's fine:
[image: Picture2]

It seems that every "R.id.something" I have in code is wrong. But there's no problem when I build debug apk, only with signed apk.

I tried Clean Project, Rebuild Project, Invalidate Cache/Restart, even restarted my pc.

There are 40 errors, same problem in all classes:
[image: Picture3]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: as you said you moved files to another package.. i think you should check the package name of all moved files is correct or not... all associated classes where you used these classes check the import lines

Answer (score 0):

> > 1 ) close your studio
> >         2 ) go to the Project_Name\Module_Name\build\outputs\apk\
> >         3 ) delete that apk
> >       4 ) restart android studio and go to Build>Generate Signed APK